# One-dimensional data in spatstat

Tags: r, statistics, spatstat

I have data of one-dimensional points (locations in a straight line). I want to check if the cluster poisson process models or Cox models are a good fit for the data.

Since my data only has x-coordinate, I tried the linear network poisson process model. However, `lppm` supports only Poisson models.

The `kppm` methods, which have the cluster models, require two-dimensional data. So, I added a dummy y-column with `zero` values and range of `(ymin=0,ymax=0.001)`. `ymax=0` returns errors during computation. Now, I am able to fit Matern cluster, etc.

My question is what would be the best way to handle one-dimensional data?

Is adding a dummy column with a non-zero range the only solution? Or did I miss some details about point patterns or process models?

Suggestions for alternatives are also welcome.